# How to get the object from array and make a new array from it

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here is the sample json data that I have:

```json
a = [
    {
        "first_name": "Andrew",
        "last_name": " ",
        "job": "actor",

    },
    {
        "first_name": "Andrew",
        "last_name": "Petrov",
        "job": "",
        "contry": "Russia"
    },
    {
        "first_name": "Andrew",
        "last_name": "Petrov",
        "contry": "Russia"
    },

]
```

And I want to extract the single object from this array and make a new array from this object.

This is the sample output which I wants to get:

```json
[
    {
        "first_name": "Andrew",
        "last_name": "Petrov",
        "job": "actor",
        "contry": "Russia"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

As simple as a[1]

[n] is the index of the array. Index starts at 0

If you mean to get an object in array in array, a[1][0]

Answer (score 1):

I think this should get you to the result you want.
Basically what I am doing is using the array.reduce method to iterate over all the objects in the input array and add the properties that are missing in the result object.

```js
let   a = [
  {
    "first_name": "Andrew",
    "last_name": " ",
    "job": "actor",
    
  },
  {
    "first_name": "Andrew",
    "last_name": "Petrov",
    "job": "",
    "contry": "Russia"
  },
  {
    "first_name": "Andrew",
    "last_name": "Petrov",
    "contry": "Russia"
  },
  
]

let result = a.reduce((prevValue, currentValue) => {for (let prop in currentValue) {
    if (currentValue[prop].trim() && !prevValue[prop]) {
    prevValue[prop] = currentValue[prop];    
  }
 
}
 return prevValue;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

In array you can get the `n th` item by providing the `index` number to it.

For example:

```js
a = [10, 11, 12]
```

if you want's to get the `10` from this array you can do `console.log(a[0])` which will log the `10` in your console. In here `a[0]` 0 is the index.

Same as in your condition: if you wants to get the object from your array you need to pass the index number of that particular object.

In your case, `a[0]` will return this output:

```js
{
    "first_name": "Andrew",
    "last_name": " ",
    "job": "actor",
}
```

Now the second case that you want is , you need to create a new array from this object.

There are number of ways to create an array, here is the simple one:

```js
const myNewArray = [a[0]]
```

If you wrap your object with big brackets, it'll create a new array.

In your case, there are some fields which are missing in objects, to get that, there are number of ways that you can use like: `reducer`, `map`, `forEach loop` etc.

Here is the example with `reducer`:

```js
let res = a.reduce((xs, cv) => {
    for (let prop in cv) {
        if (cv[prop].trim() && !xs[prop]) {
            xs[prop] = cv[prop];
        }
    }
    return xs;
}, {});

console.log("result is :", res)
```

Answer (score 0):

**1)** You can easily achieve the result if you first filter out the properties of an object and then use [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) to get the desired result

**`One -liner solution`**

```
a.reduce((acc, curr) => Object.assign({},acc,Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(curr).filter(([k, v]) => v.trim() !== ""))),{});
```

```js
const a = [
  {
    first_name: "Andrew",
    last_name: " ",
    job: "actor",
  },
  {
    first_name: "Andrew",
    last_name: "Petrov",
    job: "",
    contry: "Russia",
  },
  {
    first_name: "Andrew",
    last_name: "Petrov",
    contry: "Russia",
  },
];

const result = a.reduce((acc, curr) => Object.assign({},acc,Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(curr).filter(([k, v]) => v.trim() !== ""))),{});

console.log(result);
```